# condition in with values and without PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
UPDATE backend."orders"
  SET "statusId" = 5
WHERE "orderId" IN  (10697457,10697458)
  and "statusId" IN (0,1,2,3,4);
```

```
UPDATE backend."orders"
   SET "statusId" = 5
WHERE "orderId" IN  (VALUES (10697457),(10697458))
  and "statusId" IN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4));
```

What is the difference between these two queries?

Comment: The only difference is, that the second one needs more characters type.

Comment: The first version is more intelligible

Answer (score 1):

The two queries give the same result. The difference is the readability and the efficiency.

As explained in [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16964), the IN operator must be followed by :

> a parenthesized list of scalar expressions. The result is "true" if
>   the left-hand expression's result is equal to any of the right-hand
>   expressions

By using the keyword VALUES, you still create a list of scalar expressions, so it is correct, but it's heavier, and [the documentation (see the end of the page)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) does not recommend it :

> Tip: For simple IN tests, it's better to rely on the list-of-scalars
>   form of IN than to write a VALUES query as shown above. The list of
>   scalars method requires less writing and is often more efficient.

It may have an impact on performance (as the quote suggests) because the creation of the list of scalars may be different in memory with and without VALUES, but I don't know, someone has to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are correct but it's better to rely on the list-of-scalars form of IN than to write a VALUES query. The list of scalars form of IN method requires less writing and is often more efficient.